pythonanywhere, sqlite3 выдаёт ошибку
через редактор кода все работает, в pythonanywhere почему то нет, вот отрывок кода
db = sqlite3.connect('бд.db')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))

ошибка:
malformed database schema (users) - near "STRICT": syntax error

Проблема похоже с созданием базы, а не с селектом из неё. Так что приводите полный стек-трейс ошибки и именно тот код, на котором ошибка выходит.

Попробуй начать с указания полного пути к файлу БД, что ли...

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kirill578228/main.py", line 83, in 
c.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ?", (user_id,))
sqlite3.DatabaseError: malformed database schema (users) - near "STRICT": syntax error

указал полный путь, не помогло

вот DDL CREATE TABLE users (
id             INTEGER DEFAULT (0)
PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
user_id        INTEGER UNIQUE
NOT NULL,
username       TEXT    NOT NULL,
nickname       TEXT,
balance        INTEGER DEFAULT (0),
status         TEXT,
text           TEXT
)
STRICT;

Всё это поместите в вопрос. В комментариях нет нормального форматирования. Ну вот и попробуйте убрать STRICT из определения базы, раз на него ругается.

Весьма странно выглядит сочетание DEFAULT и AUTOINCREMENT.

STRICT поддерживается начиная с версии 3.37. Возможно, нужно обновиться?
